# Problem with a class? SHT21 library

Tags: esp32, class

I am using ESP32 and SHT21 temp+humidity sensor but while compiling the code I get the following error:

```
variable "SHT21" is not a type name
```

I see an SHT21 class defined in the SHT21.cpp file in the library folder. I don't know much about classes so could you please tell what is wrong with the SHT21 class in this case?

Here is the link to the library:
https://github.com/markbeee/SHT21

Sketch:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <Wire.h>
#include "SHT21.h"

SHT21 SHT21;

void setup()
{
  SHT21.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Humidity(%RH): ");
  Serial.print(SHT21.getHumidity());
  Serial.print("     Temperature(C): ");
  Serial.println(SHT21.getTemperature());
  
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Don't name your instance the same as the class. It confuses the compiler as it never knows what you're talking about.

Comment: Ah Ok! I see it. Thanks for the tip. It compiles without error now.